# sencha touch 2 can't launch in my android phone

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I followed exactly this tutorial http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started
My application is working on my web browser (in my laptop) and it's been generated for Android. But when I install it and launch it, I still have the loading icon on the blue screen.
Any Idea of this ?

Thnx

```
Ext.define("GS.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [{
                xtype : 'homePanel'
            }
        ]
    }
});


Ext.define('GS.view.Home', {
    extend : Ext.Panel,
    xtype : 'homePanel',

    config : {
        title : 'Home',
        iconCls : 'home',
        scrollable : true,
        styleHtmlContent : true,

        html: [
            '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
            '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
            "<p>You're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ",
            "to use tabs, lists and forms to create a simple app</p>",
            '<h2>Sencha Touch (2.0.0)</h2>'
        ].join("")
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Android OS and browser are you using?

Comment: On my phone it's ICS, and on the packager.json "androidAPILevel":"15"
My browser is chrome 20

Comment: Logcat? what have you tried? source?

Comment: I just generate the .apk using : sencha app build native. And after this I copy it into my phone and install it

Comment: Does it work in an Android emulator?  You might debug there first.  Definitely use logcat.  I've only used PhoneGap for packaging Sencha Touch 2, but I'd expect the Sencha native packager to be superior.

Comment: I'll search a tutorial on how to debug a sencha touch app on Android.
Thnx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

your code have small bugs, please try this:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Main' , {
     extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',

     config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [{
                 xtype : 'homePanel'
                }
       ]
    }
});
```

**I hope this helps. :)**

[image]

Comment: It's working with my code on the browser (computer's browser) but when I build it as native android app, it still loading...